# How to translate "durch das Bundesverwaltungsamt" from German to Spanish?

Tags: translation

I would like to translate this from German to Spanish

> durch das Bundesverwaltungsamt

It is on my Apostille document which I wish to translate.

Comment: You might want to add an attempt. I mean, there are certain rules here not allowing translations (independent of the target language).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

> a través de la Oficina Federal de Administración

Of course, it depends on the context *"durch das Bundesverwaltungsamt"* is being used in. Can you elaborate on the context, please?

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: But, I guess it even depends on the country the user is translating those documents for. If we are speaking about the German *Bundesverwaltungsamt*, the translation is perfect. But depending on the country the Federal Office of Administration might be no office at all, but a ministry (ministerio), a sectretary (secretaría), etc. depending how that country is organized.

Comment: I am sending it to the Spanish embassy and that's what is given on my German Apostille.

Comment: @tandem Then my suggestion is correct.

Comment: Are names of institions even to be translated? If I am talking about for instance the FBI in German, I would not say "the Bundesermittlungsamt". In my opinion "Bundesverwaltungsamt" stays "Bundesverwaltungsamt".

Comment: @Twinkles I got your point. A better solution would be *"a través del Bundesverwaltungsamt (Oficina Federal de Administración)"*, wouldn't it?